# RuntimeError in Devise::InvitationsController#create, Could not find a valid mapping for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I am using **devise_invitable** gem in my rails 5 application. Every time after submitting the "Send an Invitation" button, I get the error **RuntimeError in Devise::InvitationsController#create, Could not find a valid mapping for nil**

## Here is the code of application_controller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def authenticate_inviter!
        unless current_user.role=='Manager'
            if current_user.role == "Developer"
                redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access Denied! Only Manager Can Add New Developer"
            end
            super
        end
    end
    protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [ :email, :password, :password_confirmation ]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :accept_invitation, keys: [:email]
    end
end
```

## Here is the Code of User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    include DeviseInvitable::Inviter
    devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

## Here is Route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    root 'dashboard#index'
end
```

## Here is all routes:

```
                       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise_invitable/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise_invitable/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#create
   accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                                                       devise/invitations#edit
   remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)                                                       devise/invitations#destroy
      new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                                                          devise/invitations#new
          user_invitation PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#update
                          PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#update
                          POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#create
                     root GET    /                                                                                        dashboard#index
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

- I haven't created any custom invitations controller.
- I just run the following to setup and configure devise_invitable

  gem 'devise_invitable'

  bundle install

  rails generate devise_invitable:install

  rails generate devise_invitable User

  rails db:migrate

  rails generate devise_invitable:views

  restart the rails server

Here is the picture of the complete error:
[see the picture of the complete error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBB0M.png)

How can I get rid of this problem. Please help me

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question and include the relevant code, errors and logs as text. Screenshots are unreadable and cannot be searched or copied and you should make it as easy as possible for people to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved this issue by the help of [Scambra](https://github.com/scambra)

I have just changed the logic of my **Application Controller**

From:

```
def authenticate_inviter!
    unless current_user.role=='Manager'
        if current_user.role == "Developer"
            redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access Denied! Only Manager Can Add New Developer"
        end
        super
    end
end
```

To:

```
def authenticate_inviter!
      if current_user.role == "Developer"
          redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access Denied! Only Manager Can Add New Developer"
      end
      super
end
```